# Cloning HP 500GB drive to SSD - which partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, clone, hp-laptop

I am going to clone an HP Windows 10 system disk to SSD using Macrium reflect. I have done this before and it has worked well.
 
I need to shrink the main partition as I am moving from 500GB to 256GB SSD - that is fine - I will use GParted.
 
The machine was originally Win7 and upgraded to Win10.
 
My question is about the various partitions on the HP Windows HDD.  I don't want to copy any unnnecessary data as I want to make the target system partition as large as possible. The disk is formatted GPT.
 
The partitions are labelled and have size:

1. WinRE 650 MB NTFS
2. Noname FAT32 260MB
3. (None) Unformatted 128MB
4. Windows (C:) NTFS 443 GB
5. (None) 1.7 GB
6. RECOVERY (D:) 19.63GB
    
   So. Which partitions do I need to copy/clone? All of them? Some of them?

(This question is also posted on HP Community but I haven't received any answers there. Wherever I receive an answer, I will cross-post to the other forum).

Comment: Have you considered just to perform a fresh installation of Windows 10? Microsoft provides the latest install media for free and the installer automatically maximizes the main partition. You then have to migrate your data to the new installation which requires a bit of work but sometimes  afresh start also has advantages...

Comment: @Robert. The person who wants the SSD has loads of personal, installed and licenced apps and a familiar desktop. Changing appearance and layouts for a "nice clean" start is not an option - which is why system clone software exists , I guess. Thanks

Comment: AOMEI seem to offer cloning and resizing of partitions of a "live" Windows system disk. I may end up copying all these "other" partitions if it isn't clear which are vital and which are a redundant legacy of some earlier system update..

Comment: Based on the fact the user wants to keep their files.  You will want to clone all those partitions.

Comment: @ramhound With a bit more research, and splitting the cloning into two steps, I found in Macrium Reflect I could resize/shrink the Windows partition I was cloning from the Windows HDD. It was a bit awkward but it worked. It would have been easier to resize all the partition sizes in one go and the cloning in one step. I am just finishing the clone of the last partition.

Comment: As a final comment, as @ramhound suggested, I copied all the partitions, with a bit of resizing of the main Windows partition - the others were pretty small so their use of disk space wasn't really an issue. I had great problems getting the SSD to boot until I found it was "GPT" . I set the machine to boot "UEFI" then the cloned SSD worked fine to replace the HDD as the boot device. Took a long time to work out the last bit with GPT and UEFI.